# Run a script that moves director in the terminal

Tags: python, terminal, navigation, shutil

In a terminal I can move around simply using:

```
cd [file path]
```

However I need a script that does this automatically as I need to go into a a bunch of folders (around 200) and run a programme in each one.

So far I've tried things like `shutil.move()` which does not do what I need as that move the entire folder my code is in, including my IDE which causes my programme to crash.

Is there any way to run a script in python that opens up a terminal shell, navigates to a folder via a file path and then executes a programme when in that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for this, you could use the `os` module. Then do this:

```
for dir in os.listdir():
    if os.path.isdir(dir):
        os.chdir(dir)
        # Then do whatever program you wish to run
```